# Javascript - Replace consecutive spaces with hyphen

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me with replacing consecutive spaces with a hyphen? For example, I need:

```
123      321
```

to become

```
123-321
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var result = "123      321".replace(/ +/g, "-");
console.log(result);
```

`/ +/g` = at least 1 space, look globally (in the whole string)

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `\s+` will match any number of consecutive spaces (including tabs and other whitespace characters). Use that as a global pattern for `string.replace()`.

Example from a Javascript console:

```
> "a     b".replace(/\s+/g, "-")
"a-b"
```